# Getting the image from the uploaded video file using ffmpeg in mediawiki api

Tags: php, mediawiki

Using mediawiki api, I got the uploaded video file in my upload directory foler. But i need to get the snapshot image of the video . using ffmpeg we just got the image normally, but i need to run ffmpeg in mediawiki api. so, i need to know details of ffmpeg in mediawiki api and how to customize? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brion probably knows what he is talking about, but I was able to get the information with [prop=pageimages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aPageImages) more easily: https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=File:Thresher-Sharks-Use-Tail-Slaps-as-a-Hunting-Strategy-pone.0067380.s003.ogv&prop=pageimages

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Its getting fine.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have something like TimedMediaHandler installed to support the file uploads, and it's using ffmpeg to generate thumbnails, and it's configured properly already, you can fetch a thumbnail by using MediaWiki's 'imageinfo' API call:

See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Properties#imageinfo_.2F_ii